# How to get the z(elevation) value from a rendered map at webgl(Qgis2threejs plug-in)?

Tags: qgis-plugins, elevation, three-js

I am interested at getting the z value at any lat and long i want. For example i have made a 3D map using Qgis2threejs plug-in and it showed the map rendered using three.js library. The elevation value data stored at the Export_Name.js i suppose that are the one i use to create the 3D. Now Qgis2threejs uses some function to create the elevation values between the given elevation values. What i need is either the function that Qgis uses to calculate them ;either some kind of getElevation() function so i can give the lat and long values and i get back the already calculated "z" value.

Any help??

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Z value clicking on the map. 
Take a look at the *showQueryResult* function for more info.

Comment: I took a look at the showQueryResult..but if i got it right you need to click to get the Z value;as you said. I am interested at something like "for lat=xxxxxxx.xx,long=yyyyyyy.yy get me the Z value that the map has".Thanks btw :)

Comment: I have found a solution.

Comment: @prieston please describe your solution, because some of us may have the same question and would like to know how you solved it!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a small application which would take lat and lon as parameters and return elevation value.

This will be useful in any gis application, let it be threejs, openlayers or leaflet. The main advantage is that you will get the exact elevation value depending on your DEM.

You just need to capture the mouse event like click or mousemove, initiate an Ajax call along with lat and lon parameters and print the elevation value. You just need to handle CORS if this application runs in different server.

For more detailed information, refer [GIS Blogs](http://geospatialearth.in/blogs.php)